# Android: Broken menu button when text used

Tags: java, android, button, menu, android-activity

I have defined a standard onCreateOptionsMenu. The menu button works fine when my EditText box is empty. But when the EditText box has data in it, the menu button doesnt work. Any clue? Please help, i have no clue how to solve this. Thanks!

```
public class TipCalc extends Activity {

private EditText total;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    total = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    total.setOnKeyListener(mKeyListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

private OnKeyListener mKeyListener = new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if((v.getId() == R.id.EditText01 
                    && (total.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                calculate();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted for mKeyListener won't compile. `onKey` needs to return a boolean value and your code isn't returning anything. You need to post the actual code for anyone to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Thanks, i changed it. Sorry i'd prefer not post my full code. But this is basically it. All the logics the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ted. I figured it out because of your comment. Basically i was entering the onKey loop and returning true every time, so it was catching the menu button in the loop. How do i close this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if that would be correct but create `setOnClickListener` rather than `OnKeyListener`

something like this

```
    TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
    total.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
```